# Cherry pick training data (question is NOT about train/validation/test split or ml algorithms )

Tags: machine-learning

This is more of a general question and not ml-algorithm specific, are there any algorithms/tools/papers on the topic of 'selecting' training-data-entries?

Often you will have lack of training data and so it is advisable to use all of it or even try to find more data.

It seems that many people focus and developed many methods on feature selection/importance and algorithm tuning, but regarding training data the main approach is to gather more.

PS: google/literature has many information on which ml-algo to use for which data or how to split train/test data, but this is not what I need. Imbalanced classes comes closer to my question but is still not exactly what I try to find.

Comment: You say more is not always better, but what would be the basis of this claim? More data means your sample is closer to the population it represents. In what scenario would this be undesirable?

Comment: How are you measuring performance? Can you show that the apparent gains are not just an artifact of selection bias?

Comment: You don't say what purpose you want to achieve... There's the field of active learning: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_learning_(machine_learning)

Comment: Also stratified sampling...

Answer (score 2):

There are some papers related to selecting data from other domains to improve model performance:

Learning to select data for transfer learning with Bayesian Optimization
https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.05246

Instance Weighting for Domain Adaptation in NLP
http://sifaka.cs.uiuc.edu/czhai/pub/acl07.pdf